# Cascaded Pose Regression : How to run the code on 'Faces' as depicted in the research paper?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to run the code on 'Faces' data but it is not working. Can someone help me run this code on 'faces' model.

Research Paper : Cascaded Pose Regression. Piotr Dollár Peter Welinder Pietro Perona.
The Matlab code is provided at :  http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/research.html

I shall be very grateful.

Comment: To obtain the CPR Matlab code we would have to contact the owner before, am I right? Maybe I got your question wrong...

Comment: Yes, just drop him an email, he will send you the username and password , or if you want I can send you the code as well.

Comment: @Shahab any luck with the code?